# Terraform 1.2.0: Referencing resources and object mapping

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have deployed a cloud run application for currently two domains with a load balancer, which is already running. Now this setup needs to be rolled out to other domains. Because the resource setup is always the same, I face some issues:

1. I want to prevent repeating code (which is managed through a for_each)
2. Still there are some domain-specific values to cover, which i tried through a mapping table
3. Referencing resources, which are created with for_each in another resource

The first issue I solved like this, which seems to work:

**Old:**

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr_domain1" {
  name     = "cr-domain1"
  location = "europe-west6"
  project  = "my_project"

  template {
   ...
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr_domain2" {
  name     = "cr-domain2"
  location = "europe-southwest1"
  project  = "my_project"

  template {
   ...
  }
}
```

**New:**

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr" {
  for_each = toset( ["domain1", "domain2"] )
  name     = "cr-${each_key}"
  location = "tdb" # This is my second issue
  project  = "my_project"

  template {
   ...
  }
}
```

Regarding second issue I still need domain-specific location setup, which I tried to solve like this, but I am getting errors:

```
variable "cr_location" {
    type    = list(object({
       domain1 = string
       domain2 = string
    }))
    default = [{
        domain1 = "europe-west6"
        domain2 = "europe-southwest1"
    }]
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr" {
  for_each = toset( ["domain1", "domain2"] )
  name     = "cr-${each_key}"
  location = "${var.cr_location[0]}.${each.key}"
  project  = "my_project"

  template {
   ...
  }
}
```

Error is "Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required". But I have already declared it as a string in my variable "cr_location". Any idea what's the issue here? The expected output should be:

- location = "europe-west6" # For domain1
- location = "europe-southwest1" # For domain2

Also regarding issue 3 I do not understand how to referencing resources, which are created with for_each in another resource. So before my for_each in the cloud run resource block (see issue 1) I had this 2 resources:

- resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr_domain1"
- resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr_domain2"

Now I only have **resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr"**. But in my loadbalancer.tf I still have to references to the old namings (last coderow within "service"):

```
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "backendneg" {
  for_each              = toset( ["domain1", "domain2"] )
  name                  = "backendneg-${each.key}"
  project               = "my_project"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = "${var.cr_location[0]}.${each.key}" # Here same issues as issue 2
  cloud_run {
    service = google_cloud_run_service.cr_domain1.name # Old reference
  }
}
```

So if there is no "cr_domain1" anymore how do I reference to this resource? My issue is that I have to create over 20 resources like that and I couldn't figure it out how to do it. I appreciate any guideline here.

Comment: There are some things I don't quite understand, so I'll try to ask questions to clarify. First, can you try something like `region = "${var.cr_location[0].[${each.key}]"` and check if that works? Second, I don't understand the last part of the question: what would happen if you were to remove a resource whose logical name was `cr_domain1`? For that you just need to keep using the `for_each`, i.e., `service = google_cloud_run_service.cr[each.key].name`.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for your help. The region declaration still does not work. I am getting a "Error: Invalid template interpolation value" and "Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required". Regarding the last part with your suggestion I am getting "Invalid index" and "The given key does not identify an element in this collection value". It does get resolved correctly (once in domain1 and once in domain2), but the error also states "google_cloud_run_service.cr is object with 2 attributes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest here is to try and refactor the variable because it is making a lot of things harder than they should be. So I would go for this kind of a variable definition:

```
variable "cr_location" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    domain1 = "europe-west6"
    domain2 = "europe-southwest1"
  }
}
```

Then, the rest should be easy to create:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cr" {
  for_each = var.cr_location
  name     = "cr-${each.key}"
  location = each.value
  project  = "my_project"

  template {
   ...
  }
}
```

And for the network endpoint resource:

```
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "backendneg" {
  for_each              = var.cr_location
  name                  = "backendneg-${each.key}"
  project               = "my_project"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = each.value
  cloud_run {
    service = google_cloud_run_service.cr[each.key].name
  }
}
```

You could even try resource chaining with `for_each` [1] to make sure you are doing this for all the Cloud Run resources created:

```
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "backendneg" {
  for_each              = google_cloud_run_service.cr
  name                  = "backendneg-${each.key}"
  project               = "my_project"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = each.value.location
  cloud_run {
    service = each.value.name
  }
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources

Comment: Great, thanks Marko! This solved it and it is now totally clear to me.